# How to make ionic apps responsive to different screens with css?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, flexbox, ionic4

I am trying to make my ionic app responsive to certain screen dimensions. I am using CSS for styling and the @model isn't working. Here is the code.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 340px) and (max-width: 380px) {

  .srchhbar{
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(104, 102, 102);
    width: 69%;
    height: 35.5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 13px; 

  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't paste images of you code!See the How to [Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing? what is exactly not working?

Comment: @ManuelObregozo The code is basically not working. When I compile it, it doesn't work.

Comment: @FreddyThrills What I mean is, are the styles not even applied to the website? or they being overwritten by other classes? Are you sure that you are targeting the right device with those media queries?